# I want to install a new gem to my engineyard development environment for http://rubygems.org/gems/wolcanus-simple_captcha

Tags: ruby, simplecaptcha

I want to install a new gem i.e http://rubygems.org/gems/wolcanus-simple_captcha to my engineyard development environment.

Is there a simple process how, I can install the same.
I use Mongodb and need to run the mongodb scripts for the above to install.

Answer (score 0):

write in your terminal `gem 'wolcanus-simple_captcha', '~> 0.1.6'`
then `bundle install`

Comment: simple_captcha_valid function is working, able to valid the captcha.
But after checking the validation it not submit the data on mongo, showing this error :---
undefined local variable or method `connection' for SimpleCaptcha::SimpleCaptchaData:Class

Comment: Hi Gagan, this is my signup code. 

if simple_captcha_valid?
        format.html { super }
      else
        build_resource         
        resource.errors.add(:base, "Please re-enter the captcha code") if resource.valid?
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
      end
The validation is working here but after checking the validation it not submit the data. The code is not working on --- format.html { super }  it should submit the data and show a thank you message.

Comment: But it show an error  undefined local variable or method `connection' for SimpleCaptcha::SimpleCaptchaData:Class